# iOS Core Graphics - how to render UIImage to sample pixel color with 16 bit components, not 8 bit?

Tags: core-graphics, swift5, ios14, cgimage, color-space

I have a `UIImage` which comes from `ARKit`. I want to be able to sample the color of this image with high precision. Search for sample color of UIImage or CGImage returns code like below, which gives me four `UInt8` components.

I tried altering the bits per component, but don't know how to adjust other parameters of `CGContext` to make it render.

**How do I specify that CoreGraphics render UIImage using 16 bit color components? (Or something other than UInt8?)**

```
let result = renderer.image { imageRendererContext in
    
    let context = imageRendererContext.cgContext

    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)

    let maskWidth  = Int(mask.size.width)
    let maskHeight = Int(mask.size.height)
    
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * maskWidth
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
    
    guard let maskContext = CGContext(data: nil,
                                      width: maskWidth,
                                      height: maskHeight,
                                      bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                      bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                      space: colorSpace,
                                      bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo),
          let maskPointer = maskContext.data?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
        return
    }
    
    maskContext.draw(maskCGImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maskWidth, height: maskHeight))

    for x in 0 ..< maskWidth {
        for y in 0 ..< maskHeight {

            let i = bytesPerRow * Int(y) + bytesPerPixel * Int(x)
            
            let a = CGFloat(maskPointer[i + 3]) / 255.0
            let r = (CGFloat(maskPointer[i]) / a) / 255.0
            let g = (CGFloat(maskPointer[i + 1]) / a) / 255.0
            let b = (CGFloat(maskPointer[i + 2]) / a) / 255.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that as [described in the core graphics guide,](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) 16 bits per component and higher is only available on MacOS, not iOS